# Adding Custom Claims to AspNetCore Azure Authenticated Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using the AspNetCore template authorization with this line of code:

```
       services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

How can I add my custom Claims after the user is authorized by Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom cliams in `OnTokenValidated` of OIDC event :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {


            // add claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

Then in controller , you can get the claim like :

```
var role = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;
```

Comment: Nan Yu.  Do you know how i can pass my DbContext to the claims here?

Comment: I figured it out.  Had to add this:

var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();